# How to prevent an infinite loop when wrong data is entered

Tags: c++, validation

I've been writing simple codes in c++ as I am still in the beginners phase and I've noticed that when I type the wrong data into a variable within a loop an infinite loop occurs. For example:

```
int number = 0;

do{

  cout<<"Enter number: ";
  cin >> number;

}while( number != -1 );
```

If I enter a string datatype like "32ab" an infinity loop occurs. I have search for almost a week now I many of the links do not directly answer. I have found that using the ignore function can help to a certain extent by removing any invalid datatype for the cin object but this doesn't work in all cases such as if I enter "Nine" instead of nine. **So to put it simple how would one validate whether entered input is valid to its datatype, before being processed?** eg checking if an int variable is a number.

Comment: Thank you for your instant response that helped but can you by any chance explain what numeric_limits<int> does?

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works... We're here to help with problems, but not here to explain/teach you programming.

Comment: Oh alright I'm new to Stack its actually my first question. Thanks for your input

Comment: Take a look at the [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), its got a lot of info and you even get a badge after reading it! :)